# Как сохранить много файлов в папку?

Tags: python, opencv

Я работаю с файлами-картинками из папки с помощью функции `glob.iglob`:

```
for n in glob.iglob('auto\*'):
    image = cv2.imread(n)
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor( image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
```

Из  папки "auto" я беру файлы, это делается с помощью обратного слэша и *. Далее делаю преобразование их в ч/б цвет.

Далее, я хочу эти новые ч/б картинки сохранить в новую папку. В функции `cv2.imwrite` первым аргументом является путь к файлу, в нем же его имя, а вторым аргументом - ф-ция, которую я сохраняю.

Я не знаю, как записать первый аргумент, чтобы мои измененные файлы сохранились в нужную папку с названиями типа: 1,2,3,4 ...

Этот пример не работает:

```
cv2.imwrite( 'grays/*.png', image_gray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Пример:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r'/path/to/auto')

for f in p.glob('*'):
    image = cv2.imread(str(f), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_fn = str(p.parent / 'gray' / f.name)
    cv2.imwrite(new_fn, image)
```

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю у кого как, просто добавлю, может полезно.
Так как мне тоже приходится работать с файлами, и их изменение, копирование из папки в папку и прочие манипуляции с файлами, я использую команды из командной строки винды, ибо без консоли, запуск, и работа моих проектов невозможна.

Впрочем:

copy <Абсолютный путь до файла, откуда мы хотим копировать> <Абсолютный путь куда мы хотим копировать>. - Это пример когда мы хотим скопировать один файл.

Пример:

```
copy C:\test\test.txt C:\test2\
```

Также есть атрибут, наверно всем известный: "*.*"
Он применятся, если мы хотим скопировать из папки абсолютно все файлы кроме папок.

Пример:

```
copy C:\test\*.* C:\test2\
```

Но по моему легче использовать команду "XCOPY".

Пример:

```
xcopy C:\test\ C:\test2\
```

Не знаю, полезно, или нет, но так как я работаю с файлами, возможно пригодится.

Comment: Ваш ответ вообще никак не связан с вопросом. Вопрос про сохранение измененного изображения из python под определенным именем, ваш ответ - почему-то про копирование файлов.

Comment: @insolor, Значит я не понял вопрос как должно быть.